# Docker Gitlab container with nginx container

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab

I have set up a gitlab container and nginx for proxy_pass but not working.
For example, I type example.com/gitlab, it can proxy_pass to 8086 port.
It can successful to display login page with out photo and the button is not working.
I find that if I add back the port number, it is work normally http://example.com:8086/projects/new
But proxy_pass address is http://example.com/projects/new, it cannot find the file and display 404.

```
location /gitlab  {
    proxy_pass http://example.com:8086;
}
```

how can I handle this case?
http://example.com/projects/new
[image]

http://example.com:8086/projects/new
[image]

Comment: your domain name that you want to access from the outside is the same domain that you make proxy_pass ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Nginx container is listen 80 and 443 port and it will proxy pass to different container port in same host

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `GITLAB_HOST` env in to container

```
docker run -e GITLAB_HOST=http://example.com/gitlab ....
```

and pass the request header and proxy port to the proxy server in nginx config

```
location /gitlab  {
    proxy_pass http://example.com:8086;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_set_header Host           $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP      $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
}
```

Comment: Not working. it will redirect to :http://example.com/users/sign_in when you type:http://example.com/gitlab

Comment: which Gitlab image you're using

Comment: gitlab/gitlab-ee   latest